# Mathematica notebook directing link to an empty page

Tags: mac-os-x, hyperlink

In a notebook that I'm created with a Hyperlink, Mathematica directs me to my google home page upon clicking of that link.
Is this a bug or a user problem?

Any help is appreciated

Edit:

In Wolfram Language input ,

```
Hyperlink["https://math.stackexchange.com/"]
```

results in a new browser appearing but does not direct me to the designated site in the hyperlink.

The same issue is also seen in Plain text form where I have the link "https://math.stackexchange.com/" typed in the notebook.

Comment: Almost certainly it is not a bug. Without the code you used to generate the `Hyperlink` it is hard to know how to help you. If you post it I can tell you what went wrong.

Comment: @b3m2a1
 I have made an edit to the OP. Please tell me it is not sufficiently clear.

Comment: I think it will also be necessary to mention the OS you are using, the Mathematica version and which browser you are using or is opened by the link...

Comment: Works ok on Win10 V11.2

Comment: @AlbertRetey I wouldn't have thought the OS made any differences in such a case. But I'm on a mac OS.

Comment: Works on Win 7, Mma 11.2

Comment: as Mathematica starts an external program, of course the OS is involved. My guess is that there is something wrong with your setup - and that of course is also OS dependent. Does `open "https://math.stackexchange.com/"` from the commandline work for you?

Comment: I could reproduce this earlier today on OS X, but not anymore.

Comment: @Szabolcs See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is Google Chrome on OSX. You could have verified that it is indeed not a problem of Mathematica by using your Mail app and clicking on one of the links from your emails. You will experience the same bug.

The solution is as simple: You should see a small indicator in the top right corner of Chrome that tells you it really really would like to be updated. Once updated and restarted, the issue is gone.